# Semantic release always uses semantic release bot user instead of own for git commits

Tags: git, github-actions, semantic-release

I'm using semantic release and because I want to use signed commits I want to use my own git user.
I have a `publishCmd` configured (`@semantic-release/exec`) which is a shell script and executes some logic, including git commands.
In there I've set `git config --global user.name "$GIT_USERNAME"`, `git config --global user.email "$GIT_EMAIL"` and `git config --global user.signingKey "$GIT_SIGNING_KEY"`  in that script.
I think that should be enough for `git` to be able to sign commits but the commit is always from the `semantic-release-bot` instead of my own configured user.

Is there a way to use my own user instead of the `semantic-release-bot`-user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a hint in this plugin: https://github.com/semantic-release/git#environment-variables

I've set these environment variables and now it uses my git user. I do not use this plugin actively so it was very confusing.

```
GIT_AUTHOR_NAME
GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL
GIT_COMMITTER_NAME
GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont think its possible, as from https://github.com/semantic-release/exec#publishcmd there is no option to pass git user, email & signing key...
You can open an issue there and ask them to add this feature request